# Pass a String to a Command that is Expecting a File

Tags: bash

I have a command line program that is expecting to be passed a configuration file e.g.

```
sphinx --config /some/config_file
```

I'm calling this command from inside a ruby program where I'm currently dynamically generating the config file before writing it to disk, this seems like a waste as the file is only every used once and just deleted again straight after.

I was wondering if there's a way to avoid writing the file to disk and just passing in something that the program will think is a file but really hasn't been written to disk?

Comment: This largely depends on what command line options `sphinx` makes available. Many unix-y utilities are able to accept input via STDIN, but I'm not sure if that's the case with this utility. If anything, you could just make a very small ramdisk and write the file there. That would be *very* fast.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your program reads the file, you might be able to use a named pipe, but it's very likely that it won't work; named pipes are not random access.